# Socle series and radical series have same length

Tags: modules, representation-theory, radicals, socle

I have been given a module $V$ of finite length $l(V)=n$. If I am not wrong if follows from Jordan- Hölder theorem that the socle series and radical series have also finite length since they are filtrations (I proved that in each step we gain at least one dimension), but now I am asked to prove that both series have same finite length.

If $V$ is semisimple it follows that the length is 1 in both cases...could it be some kind of induction valid?

Moreover, I have tried to relate both series, but I would appreciate any hint since I am a little bit confused. I have been given the following hint: "prove that the composition $rad(V) \longrightarrow V \longrightarrow V/Soc^{n-1}(V)$ is zero", but I don't know how to use it...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not [delete and repost](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4712377/29335) questions.  To update your question, use the edit button.  If this continues to happen it will be viewed as dodging moderation by shedding comments on the previous iteration. I do appreciate you have improved this question though. Please remember for next time.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the underlying ring.

Note that $Soc(V)= (0 :_V Rad (A))$.

And due to the finiteness condition, $Rad (V)= (Rad(A))V$

(in general $Rad (V) \supseteq (Rad(A))V$).

So, $$Rad^k(V)= (Rad(A))^kV$$ and $$Soc^k(V)= (0 :_V (Rad (A))^k)$$ So if $k_1$ is the least integer such that $(Rad(A))^{k_1}V=0$ then $(0 :_V (Rad (A))^{k_1})=V$ and $k_2$ is the least integer such that $(0 :_V (Rad (A))^{k_2})=V$ then $(Rad(A))^{k_2}V=0$ implying $k_1=k_2$